# Arduino IDE not working Linux Mint

Tags: java, linux, arduino

I just installed the Arduino IDE using the apt-get command on Linux Mint. When I run the program I am first greeted with this window:

[Adruino IDE Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEk2U.png)

After picking a folder to hold my sketches nothing ever happens.

I ran the program from the command line so I can see what the errors are and this is what it shows:

```
arduino ide
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch) thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
    at processing.app.Editor.populateSerialMenu(Editor.java:962)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildToolsMenu(Editor.java:691)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildMenuBar(Editor.java:476)
    at processing.app.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:205)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:705)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:670)
    at processing.app.Base.handleNew(Base.java:566)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:306)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:195)
```

I tried to reinstall Java on my machine with no avail. Can someone help me make sense of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I guess there was something wrong with the version of Java I was using. I installed OpenJDK 8 and set that as my default Java and everything worked from there.